# Override Firefox Insecure Warnings with about:config

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, html5-canvas, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to write a simple batch script to take some screenshots of internal webpages on my end and came across the fact that firefox has this ability to render the window to canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawWindow(window, 0,0, 100, 200, "rgb(255,255,255)");
console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

However, this seems to be reserved only form extensions and throws an Error: The operation is insecure.

I don't need to publish this to anyone else and I'm happy to make some internal adjustment to only my Firefox to avoid creating an extension. Is there some sort of about:config setting (or something else) I can tweak to just let this go through even if it's not in an extension?

Comment: Why don't you use a different tool. Selenium makes it easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I've used http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/ in the past with good results. There's something similar floating around for Moz, too.

Comment: DaggNabbit: Unfortunately, this will be on windows machines. 
epascarello: I haven't started with selenium, and though that snippet does look simple enough, I'm wondering if Setting up Selenium and actually getting it going is going to take quite a while to do.

Comment: Wait, does Selenium IDE perform screenshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `about:config` and set `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true`
Restart
Go to the tab you want to take screenshot
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
Switch environment to Browser
Paste the following snippet

```
var canvas = gBrowser.contentDocument.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawWindow(window, 0,0, 100, 200, "rgb(255,255,255)");
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Place the cursor at the end of the last line
Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
Mission accomplished!